# Can I have a magic bow as my pact weapon without getting the Improved Pact Weapon Eldritch Invocation?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, eldritch-invocations

The Warlock's Pact of the Blade feature specifies that you can only create melee weapons, but you can also turn a magic weapon into your pact weapon (without specifying that it's only melee weapons). Can I have a magic bow as my pact weapon without getting the Improved Pact Weapon Eldritch Invocation?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Concerning magic weapons, the Pact of the Blade option for the [Pact Boon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) feature says (PHB, pg. 108):

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon.

The qualifying word “melee” is notably absent, so you may perform the ritual to make a magical bow your pact weapon; the improved pact weapon invocation is not necessary.

As user RevenantBacon pointed out in comments, this is explained in further detail in the [*Sage Advice Compendium*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#Warlock) ([p. 6 of the PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=6)):

> **If a warlock uses Pact of the Blade to bond with a magic weapon, does that weapon have to be a melee weapon, and can the warlock change the weapon’s form?**
>
> [...]
>
> You can also use Pact of the Blade to bond with a magic weapon, turning it into your pact weapon. ***This magic weapon doesn’t have to be a melee weapon, so you could use the feature on a *+1 longbow*, for instance.***
>
> [...]